# Magento 2 Data Migration Tool

Tags: magento2, data-migration-tool

I have developed new Website in Magento 2.2.4 latest version and now trying to migrate data from old website Magento 1.9.3 version.

I have searched on forums and found some links that we can migrate data from Magento to Magento 2.

I have installed default Magento Migration tool **"data-migration-tool"** with composer.Module is successfully installed but I don't have idea how it will work.

I have read magento guide but I am not getting that where are the settings of databases(magento and Magento2) and how to run Migration tool.

I am following Magento 2 link:

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/migration-migrate-settings.html

Please help me to Migrate data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to do some changes in config.xml

your config.xml is here

\vendor\magento\data-migration-tool\etc\opensource-to-opensource\1.9.3\config.xml

set database names
and make all .xml.dist file to .xml file
set magento1's crypt key

and run command

```
 bin/magento migrate:settings [-r|--reset] {<path to config.xml>}
 bin/magento migrate:data [-r|--reset] {<path to config.xml>}
 bin/magento migrate:delta [-r|--reset] {<path to config.xml>}
```

**Can you please check in your config.xml, if your are missing,
and also make sure that etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.2.4/ all files like map.xml and setting.xml all files are with .xml extension not in .xml.dist**

```
 <source>
    <database host="localhost" name="magento1" user="root" password=""/>
</source>
<destination>
    <database host="localhost" name="magento2" user="root" password=""/>
</destination>
<options>
    <map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.2.4/map.xml</map_file>
    <eav_map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/map-eav.xml</eav_map_file>
    <eav_document_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/eav-document-groups.xml</eav_document_groups_file>
    <eav_attribute_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/eav-attribute-groups.xml</eav_attribute_groups_file>
    <log_map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/map-log.xml</log_map_file>
    <log_document_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/log-document-groups.xml</log_document_groups_file>
    <settings_map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/settings.xml</settings_map_file>
    <customer_map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/map-customer.xml</customer_map_file>
    <customer_document_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/customer-document-groups.xml</customer_document_groups_file>
    <delta_document_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/deltalog.xml</delta_document_groups_file>
    <order_grids_document_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/order-grids-document-groups.xml</order_grids_document_groups_file>
    <map_document_groups>etc/opensource-to-opensource/map-document-groups.xml</map_document_groups>
    <class_map>etc/opensource-to-opensource/class-map.xml</class_map>
    <tier_price_map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/map-tier-price.xml</tier_price_map_file>
    <stores_map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/map-stores.xml</stores_map_file> 
    <customer_attribute_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/customer-attribute-groups.xml</customer_attribute_groups_file>

    <!--
    In case bulk_size=0 it will be auto-detected for every document.
    -->
    <bulk_size>100</bulk_size>
    <!--
    Set direct_document_copy = 1 for better performance.
    NOTE: 'source' and 'destination' databases MUST be placed on the same MySQL instance
    and 'destination' user MUST be granted with 'SELECT' permissions on 'source' database
     -->
    <direct_document_copy>0</direct_document_copy>
    <source_prefix></source_prefix>
    <dest_prefix></dest_prefix>
    <auto_resolve_urlrewrite_duplicates>0</auto_resolve_urlrewrite_duplicates>
    <log_file>migration.log</log_file>
    <progress_bar_format>%percent%% [%bar%] Remaining Time: %remaining%</progress_bar_format>
    <upgrade_customer_password_hash>1</upgrade_customer_password_hash>
    <edition_migrate>opensource-to-opensource</edition_migrate>
    <edition_number>1.9.2.4</edition_number>
    <init_statements_source>SET NAMES utf8;</init_statements_source>
    <init_statements_destination>SET NAMES utf8;</init_statements_destination>
    <crypt_key>f5b73dxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx(Your magento1.9.3.0's crypt key)</crypt_key>
</options>
```

Comment: Hi @Rutvee, followed steps but getting errors :  Invalid map filename: vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/settings.xml

Comment: Can you please update your config.xml file code

Comment: I have updated but still not working,can you please write  steps in your answer so I can configure it.

Comment: @akgola 
I have added code of config.xml which are required please check with your config.xml
Let me know if you have any query

Comment: ,thanks I have update the code and its now working.

Comment: @akgola  cheers!!

Comment: ,Have you Idea how much time to take migrate 10k products and how to map images after migration?

Comment: It's depend your database size
our database size is 10 GB
so it took almost 7-8 daya

Comment: How to sync real time data?we have backup of this month but magento site is live and it will have new customers and Order.How to handle this situation?

Comment: bin/magento migrate:delta [-r|--reset] {<path to config.xml>}
Delta will do rest things

Comment: Hi @Rutvee ,I am getting issue "No such entity with email xxx " when creating customer from frontend.Have you any idea about this issue?

Comment: @akgola have try below code?
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
UPDATE `store` SET store_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `store_group` SET group_id = 0 WHERE name='Default';
UPDATE `store_website` SET website_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `customer_group` SET customer_group_id = 0 WHERE customer_group_code='NOT LOGGED IN';
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;

Comment: I have tried it many times but still same error here.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to configure the migration, go through https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/migration/migration-tool-configure.html

Next, go through https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/migration/migration-migrate-settings.html to know how to migrate settings.

and then to know how to migrate data read https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/migration/migration-migrate-data.html

You can always refer [Magento Migration Guide](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/migration/bk-migration-guide.html) while Magento migration.